# Photos sync from iphotos to iphone

Tags: photos.app

I downloaded all my photos from iPhone to Macbook Pro, and now that I have a new iPhone, I want to download from my iPhoto's photo album to my iPhone.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Connect your new iPhone to the MacBook, then in iTunes, click on the device and click on Photos to select what is copied to your phone. See detailed steps on [Apple's website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201313).